# Save byte array as .png/.jpg file in QT

Tags: qt, qpixmap

This is what I have so far:

```
QFile file(fileName);  
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);  
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap.loadFromData((const uchar *) imageBuffer_pointer, (sizeof(imageRows) * sizeof(imageCols));  
pixmap.save(&file, "JPG");  
pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
```

But it only produces 0 byte image files

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you have created a valid image from the data? For example by checking the pixmap's size?

Comment: Yes, the image is valid. I am able to display it on QT with a live feed, now I want to record it

Comment: nevermind, it turned out it was recording a frame after what I thought it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to just give the `save()` function a file name as a first parameter:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap.loadFromData((const uchar *) imageBuffer_pointer, 
    (sizeof(imageRows) * sizeof(imageCols));
pixmap.save(fileName, "JPG");
```

Comment: Oops the image was not valid, this also cleared up unecessary code thanks